# npm installation error in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I am trying to install npm using command:  `curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh` but I am getting following error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/tmp/npm.8156/package/bin/read-package-json.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:935:3

/tmp/npm.8156/package/lib/utils/unsupported.js:28
        console.error(`a bug known to break npm. Please update to at least ${r
                      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at /tmp/npm.8156/package/bin/npm-cli.js:19:21
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/npm.8156/package/bin/npm-cli.js:92:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)

/tmp/npm.8156/package/lib/utils/unsupported.js:28
        console.error(`a bug known to break npm. Please update to at least ${r
                      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at /tmp/npm.8156/package/bin/npm-cli.js:19:21
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/npm.8156/package/bin/npm-cli.js:92:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
It failed
```

What is cause of this error? What can be done to fix this?

Comment: I would simply reinstall Node.js. I'm using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) which makes things much easier.

Comment: Looks like a known thing? https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18524

Comment: Can this be done using a different command? or should I use workaround mentioned here- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18524#issuecomment-362569934